# Why is my click event not being emitted for Angular 8.0?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I want to listen a click event on a child component from a parent component, but the event is not emitting to the parent.

Child Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  templateUrl: './child-component.component.html',
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() click = new EventEmitter<string>();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onClick() {
    console.log('click');
    this.click.emit();
  }

}
```

Child template:

```
<label>
    <div (click)="onClick()"></div>
</label>
```

Parent Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'parent-component',
  templateUrl: './parent-component.component.html',
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onChildClicked() {
    console.log('Child Clicked!');
  }

}
```

Parent template:

```
<input type="checkbox" ngModel (click)="onChildClicked()">
<child-component></child-component>
```

When I click, I get the first message in the console from the child, but I'm not getting the second message, which tells me the event is not being emitted.

Answer (score 2):

Change parent-template from:

```
<input type="checkbox" ngModel (click)="onChildClicked()">
<child-component></child-component>
```

to:

```
<input type="checkbox" ngModel >
<child-component (click)="onChildClicked()"></child-component>
```

The child-component emits the event, so the handler needs to be located on the child's tag inside the parent's template and not on some arbitrary element like the input.

Answer (score 1):

Try a value in you emit.

```
this.click.emit('text');
```

Also you really need to pick a different name than click since the click output might clash with ng click

Answer (score 1):

Click event should be on the  element

```
 <child-component (click)="onChildClicked()"></child-component>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to listen to attach the event emitter to the child-component like so:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d4hhzj

Tip: when creating output properties in angular make sure that the names you pick are different from the native events.
Edit: otherwise you might experience strange (expected) behaviour. If your event-emitter is called click. when you listen for (click)="handleClick()" in the parent, handleClick will actually be called twice